# FacetWP template - Woocommerce product loop - show price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, faceted-search, facetwp

I'm using the FacetWP plugin to display Woocommerce products in a custom page.

I built a template with product loop that displays product thumbnail, title,  excerpt and product price, but i'm struggling to display the price. It just won't show up.

My product loop template looks like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="facet-courses">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft')); ?>
      <div><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
      <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
      <div>
        <?php
            global $post; $product; 
            $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
            wc_price($product->get_price_html()); 
            ?>
      </div>
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have tried to fetch the price also with `$product = new WC_Product( $post->ID );`
or `$product = get_product(get_the_ID());` but none of it seems to work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It would be awesome to know why did I deserve the downvote ?!?

Answer (score 1):

got it, missing `echo`, so `echo wc_price($product->get_price_html());`